# Integration with Grassmann variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, grassmann-numbers

How to show that
$$
\int d\Psi d\bar {\Psi}e^{i \int d^{4}x\bar {\Psi} \hat {A} \Psi} = det (\hat {A})?
$$
$\Psi , \bar {\Psi}$ refers to Dirac spinors (the second is $\bar {\Psi} = \Psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$).

Comment: Related: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_integral#Gaussian_integrals_over_Grassmann_variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First discretize the spacetime, assign a fermion pair $\bar{\psi}(i)$ and $\psi(i)$ at each point i.

Then assuming operator $\hat{A}$ is symmetric, hence which can be diagonalized by a unitary operator whose determinant is one, the path integral can be written in the following way:

$$\int \Pi_{i} d\psi(i)d\bar{\psi}(i) e^{i \delta \sum \bar{\psi}(i)\lambda_i \psi(i)}$$

where $\delta$ is the discretized spacetime volume element and $\lambda_is$ are the eigenvalues of $\hat{A}$.

Now the path integral can be written as a product of many grassmanian integrals. In particular each one is:

$$\int d\psi(i) d\bar{\psi}(i) e^{i\delta \lambda_i \bar{\psi}(i) \psi(i)}\\
  =\int d\psi(i) d\bar{\psi}(i) (1+i\delta \lambda_i \bar{\psi}(i) \psi(i)) = i\delta \lambda_i $$

Multiplying all these together you get the determinant of $\hat{A}$ up to some irrelevant constant factor.